# How to tell if a backup log chain is broken?

Tags: sql-server, backup

I had a situation where the Native Backups were being made on a Server.
I happened to see in `msdb` that there was a third party backup tool (`AppAssure`) that was also taking VSS (kind-of) `backup to virtual device`.

At some interval, the AppAssure (backup being made to `VIRTUAL DEVICE`) was doing a `COPY_ONLY backup` and at some other interval it was doing a `FULL backup` breaking the log chain.

Is there any way(`T-SQL query`) to know when a backup log chain is broken?

Here is a screenshot of the situation from February.
[image]

Comment: Did you checked through (Restore Headeronly ...) from there it will confirm your log chain sequence. As per attached screen shot by you, it's just showing the Backup size with media name.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Reference Reading / Similar Q&As

You might want to check out my [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/171497/15356) that I posted in response to the question:  [Will VSS backups break logchain?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/171493/15356) (dba.stackexchange.com)

The explanation in my answer also links to the question [How can I backup an SQL Server database using Windows Server Backup?](https://serverfault.com/q/543515/145804) (serverfault.com) which was also [answered](https://serverfault.com/a/820843/145804) by myself.

---

### Transaction Log Chain

When a Transaction Log (TLOG) backup is performed, the backup information is stored in the **msdb** database in various tables. The information stored will contain information like `backup_type`, `logical_device_name`, `physical_device_name`, `is_copy_only`, `is_snapshot`, and various `..._lsn` columns (lsn = log sequence number).

You can retrieve the transaction log backup chain information from your SQL Server instance via the msdb database with the following script:

```
/* ==================================================================
 Author......:  hot2use 
 Date........:  25.04.2018
 Version.....:  0.1
 Server......:  localhost (first created for)
 Database....:  msdb
 Owner.......:  -
 Table.......:  various
 Type........:  Script
 Name........:  ADMIN_Retrieve_Backup_History_Information.sql
 Description.:  Retrieve backup history information from msdb database
 ............   
 ............   
 ............       
 History.....:   0.1    h2u First created
 ............       
 ............       
================================================================== */
SELECT /* Columns for retrieving information */
       -- CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) AS SRVNAME, 
       msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name,
       msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_start_date,
       msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date,
       -- msdb.dbo.backupset.expiration_date, 
       
       CASE msdb.dbo.backupset.type
            WHEN 'D' THEN 'Full'
            WHEN 'I' THEN 'Diff'
            WHEN 'L' THEN 'Log'
       END  AS backup_type,
       -- msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_size / 1024 / 1024 as [backup_size MB],  
       msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.logical_device_name,
       msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.physical_device_name,
       -- msdb.dbo.backupset.name AS backupset_name,
       -- msdb.dbo.backupset.description,
       msdb.dbo.backupset.is_copy_only,
       msdb.dbo.backupset.is_snapshot,
       msdb.dbo.backupset.checkpoint_lsn,
       msdb.dbo.backupset.database_backup_lsn,
       msdb.dbo.backupset.differential_base_lsn,
       msdb.dbo.backupset.first_lsn,
       msdb.dbo.backupset.fork_point_lsn,
       msdb.dbo.backupset.last_lsn
FROM   msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily
       INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset
            ON  msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.media_set_id = msdb.dbo.backupset.media_set_id 
                
        /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Generic WHERE statement to simplify selection of more WHEREs    
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
WHERE  1 = 1
       
       /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
       WHERE statement to find Device Backups with '{' and date n days back
       ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
       -- AND     physical_device_name LIKE '{%'
       
       /* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       WHERE statement to find Backups saved in standard directories, msdb.dbo.backupfile AS b 
       ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
       -- AND     physical_device_name  LIKE '[fF]:%'                          -- STANDARD F: Backup Directory
       -- AND     physical_device_name  NOT LIKE '[nN]:%'                      -- STANDARD N: Backup Directory
       
       -- AND     physical_device_name  NOT LIKE '{%'                          -- Outstanding Analysis
       -- AND     physical_device_name  NOT LIKE '%$\Sharepoint$\%' ESCAPE '$' -- Sharepoint Backs up to Share
       -- AND     backupset_name NOT LIKE '%Galaxy%'                           -- CommVault Sympana Backup
       
       
       /* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       WHERE Statement to find backup information for a certain period of time, msdb.dbo.backupset AS b 
       ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
       AND    (CONVERT(datetime, msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_start_date, 102) >= GETDATE() - 7)  -- 7 days old or younger
       AND    (CONVERT(datetime, msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_start_date, 102) <= GETDATE())  -- n days old or older
       
       */
       
       /* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       WHERE Statement to find backup information for (a) given database(s) 
       ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
       AND database_name IN ('AdventureWorks2012') -- database names
       -- AND     database_name IN ('rtc')  -- database names
           
        /* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ORDER Clause for other statements
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
        --ORDER BY        msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name, msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_finish_date -- order clause
           
        ---WHERE msdb..backupset.type = 'I' OR  msdb..backupset.type = 'D'
ORDER BY
       --2,
       
       2       DESC,
       3       DESC
```

<sup>**Caution:** The where clause currently select the AdventureWorks2012 database</sup>

### Broken Transaction Log Chain

The (transaction) log chain is never broken unless one of the following conditions is met:

- a Transaction Log backup file was deleted
- a Transaction Log backup file is not accessible (somewhere in a backup device; 3rd-party backup solution)
- the database is in SIMPLE recovery model
- a Transaction Log backup was performed with the option `TRUNCATE_ONLY`

### Your Situation

In the screenshot you provided you have a `FULL` backup of the database that is `is_copy_only` and shortly after a `FULL` backup that is **not** `is_copy_only`. Now what you don't know:

**Is the second `FULL`, non-`is_copy_only` backup a snapshot or not?**

If you use my script from above and change the `WHERE` clause to match your database name, you might find out that that `FULL` backup that is not `is_copy_only` might just be a `is_snapshot`.

And that might just open up a new question:

**Will the `FULL`, `is_snapshot` database backup of my database break the log backup chain?**

### But...

....whichever way this goes, as long as you have an unbroken chain of `FULL` and `TLOG` backups you can access, you can still restore your database to any point in time, even if you have another `FULL` backup in-between.

You can verify this with the output of my script for your database, by looking at the `first_lsn` and `last_lsn` numbers. They should match up, even when bypassing a `FULL` backup.

### Better Be Safe Than Sorry

I have an `AdminDB2` database on one of my instances. I created a `TLOG` backup, modified data, performed a `FULL` backup, modified data, performed a `TLOG` backup, ....

Lets have a look at my backup history of my `AdminDB2`:

```
dbname    backup_start_date       backup_finish_date            type    Log   physical_device_name                                          C   S   checkpoint_lsn   dbase_backup_lsn     dlsn  first_lsn           flsn    last_lsn
AdminDB2    2018-04-25 17:29:08.000 2018-04-25 17:29:08.000 TLOG    NULL    C:\SQL\Backup\AdminDB2\TLOG\AdminDB2_TLOG_20180425_172908.trn   0   0   36000002022400042   36000002022400042   NULL    36000002021900001   NULL    36000002025100001
AdminDB2    2018-04-25 17:28:48.000 2018-04-25 17:28:48.000 Full    NULL    C:\SQL\Backup\AdminDB2\FULL\AdminDB2_FULL_20180425_172848.bak   0   0   36000002022400042   36000002018900037   NULL    36000002022400042   NULL    36000002024200001
AdminDB2    2018-04-25 17:28:23.000 2018-04-25 17:28:23.000 TLOG    NULL    C:\SQL\Backup\AdminDB2\TLOG\AdminDB2_TLOG_20180425_172823.trn   0   0   36000002018900037   36000002018900037   NULL    36000002021500001   NULL    36000002021900001
AdminDB2    2018-04-25 17:28:07.000 2018-04-25 17:28:07.000 TLOG    NULL    C:\SQL\Backup\AdminDB2\TLOG\AdminDB2_TLOG_20180425_172807.trn   0   0   36000002018900037   36000002018900037   NULL    36000002018400001   NULL    36000002021500001
AdminDB2    2018-04-25 17:27:32.000 2018-04-25 17:27:32.000 Full    NULL    C:\SQL\Backup\AdminDB2\FULL\AdminDB2_FULL_20180425_172732.bak   0   0   36000002018900037   36000001990800037   NULL    36000002018900037   NULL    36000002020600001
AdminDB2    2018-04-25 17:15:00.000 2018-04-25 17:15:00.000 TLOG    NULL    C:\SQL\Backup\AdminDB2\TLOG\AdminDB2_TLOG_20180425_171500.trn   0   0   36000002016000003   36000001990800037   NULL    36000002018100001   NULL    36000002018400001
```

<sub>The order is date descending</sub>

You can see the last `TLOG` backup at the top, the previous `FULL` (in-between) backup at `2018-04-25 17:28:48.000`, the previous `TLOG` backup at `2018-04-25 17:28:23.000`,  and so on.

To restore the `AdminDB2` database to the current point-in-time I would have to use the first `FULL` backup from `2018-04-25 17:27:32.000` (because I deleted the in-between `FULL` backup) together with all the `TLOG` backups.

Let's give that a try.

1. Delete the `FULL` backup file `AdminDB2_FULL_20180425_172848.bak` on my disk (or rename it), just because it is the one in-between.
2. Open up the Restore GUI in SSMS and add ..

   - the `FULL` backup `AdminDB2_FULL_20180425_172732.bak`
   - all the `TLOG` backup files

     - AdminDB2_TLOG_20180425_172807.trn
     - AdminDB2_TLOG_20180425_172823.trn
     - AdminDB2_TLOG_20180425_172908.trn
3. Make sure i set the option `Overwrite the existing database (WITH REPLACE)`
4. Perform the **restore** (or script the statement out into a query window)

#### Script

```
USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE [AdminDB2] FROM  DISK = N'C:\SQL\BACKUP\AdminDB2\FULL\AdminDB2_FULL_20180425_172732.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5, REPLACE
RESTORE LOG [AdminDB2] FROM  DISK = N'C:\SQL\BACKUP\AdminDB2\LOG\AdminDB2_LOG_20180425_172807.trn' WITH  FILE = 1,  NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5
RESTORE LOG [AdminDB2] FROM  DISK = N'C:\SQL\BACKUP\AdminDB2\LOG\AdminDB2_LOG_20180425_172823.trn' WITH  FILE = 1,  NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5
RESTORE LOG [AdminDB2] FROM  DISK = N'C:\SQL\BACKUP\AdminDB2\LOG\AdminDB2_LOG_20180425_172908.trn' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5

GO
```

#### Output

```
15 percent processed.
30 percent processed.
45 percent processed.
60 percent processed.
75 percent processed.
90 percent processed.
100 percent processed.
Processed 848 pages for database 'AdminDB2', file 'AdminDB' on file 1.
Processed 2 pages for database 'AdminDB2', file 'AdminDB_log' on file 1.
RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 850 pages in 0.134 seconds (49.502 MB/sec).
100 percent processed.
Processed 0 pages for database 'AdminDB2', file 'AdminDB' on file 1.
Processed 2 pages for database 'AdminDB2', file 'AdminDB_log' on file 1.
RESTORE LOG successfully processed 2 pages in 0.005 seconds (3.027 MB/sec).
100 percent processed.
Processed 0 pages for database 'AdminDB2', file 'AdminDB' on file 1.
Processed 1 pages for database 'AdminDB2', file 'AdminDB_log' on file 1.
RESTORE LOG successfully processed 1 pages in 0.005 seconds (0.390 MB/sec).
100 percent processed.
Processed 0 pages for database 'AdminDB2', file 'AdminDB' on file 1.
Processed 2 pages for database 'AdminDB2', file 'AdminDB_log' on file 1.
RESTORE LOG successfully processed 2 pages in 0.005 seconds (3.125 MB/sec).
```

...and the database is back ONLINE.

### Summary

The backup chain only breaks when you lose the TLOG backups in-between, other than that you can restore a database from a `FULL` backup a long time ago and just add all the `TLOG` backups.

### However...

...it is faster to have a more recent `FULL`, `DIFF` and `TLOG` backups handy.

---

<sub>Additional information in response to comment: *Transaction Log backup was performed with the option TRUNCATE_ONLY - when this happens, is there any way to know this by T-SQL query*</sub>

### Backing Up Transaction Log With Truncate_only

In previous versions of SQL Server prior to SQL Server 2008 you could use the following statement:

```
 BACKUP LOG [AdminDB2] WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY
```

This has been deprecated and is no longer supported. You will receive an error message like the following:

```
Msg 155, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
'TRUNCATE_ONLY' is not a recognized BACKUP option.
```

The new method is to backup to disk `NUL` and is performed with the following command:

```
BACKUP LOG [AdminDB2] TO DISK='NUL'
```

This will return the following information:

```
Processed 1 pages for database 'AdminDB2', file 'AdminDB_log' on file 1.
BACKUP LOG successfully processed 1 pages in 0.001 seconds (1.464 MB/sec).
```

> **Advisory**
> Do **NOT** use this in production. You will lose the ability to restore to a point-in-time during that TLOG backup.

***Reference:** [BACKUP (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (Microsoft Docs)*

Your backup history will show this as:

```
dbname      backup_start_date       backup_finish_date      type ldev  pdev C   S   checkpoint_lsn   dbase_backup_lsn     dlsn  first_lsn           flsn    last_lsn
AdminDB2    2018-04-26 09:35:05.000 2018-04-26 09:35:05.000 Log NULL    NUL 0   0   36000002030100002   36000002022400042   NULL    36000002033400001   NULL    36000002033700001
```

The information for the `logical_device_name` (`ldev`) and `physical_device_name` (`pdev`) will both contain the value `NULL`. This is a sign that a `BACKUP LOG ...` was performed with a `TRUNCATE_ONLY` (new: `TO DISK='NUL'`). You will have lost the ability to restore past this point using Transaction Log backups.

---

<sub>Additional information in response to comment: *Yes - this was a is_snapshot = 1 [backup]*</sub>

### is_snapshot

Please read the section **is_snapshot** in my [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/185834/15356) to the question [Use of third-party VSS backup plus native SQL backup](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/185854/15356)

From my original answer:

> If the database backup history has the flag `is_snapshot` set to `1` then you know that this backup was performed using a 3rd-party software that triggered the [SQL Server Writer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175536(v=sql.120).aspx) (VSS Service for SQL Server) which allowed the 3rd-party software to backup the database almost instantaneously.
>
> From the official documentation on what Snapshot Backups are:
>
> > SQL Server snapshot backup is accomplished in cooperation with third-party hardware or software vendors, or both. These vendors use SQL Server features that are designed for this purpose. The underlying backup technology creates an instantaneous copy of the data that is being backed up. The instantaneous copying is typically accomplished by splitting a mirrored set of disks or by creating a copy of a disk block when it is written. This preserves the original. At restore time, the original is made available immediately and synchronization of the underlying disks occurs in the background. This results in almost instantaneous restore operations.
>
> ***Reference:** [Snapshot Backups](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189548(v=sql.105).aspx) (Microsoft Technet)*
>
> A backup created using this feature can also be restored almost instantaneously.
>
> ### Summary
>
> The 3rd-party backups should be marked as `is_snapshot = 1` and `is_copy_only = 1`. These backups will not conflict with additional backup steps/procedures performed using native SQL Server `BACKUP DATABASE...`, `BACKUP DATABASE ... WITH DIFFERENTIAL....` and `BACKUP LOG...` statements. The 3rd-party database backups are not part of an existing backup set.

I hope this information is sufficient.

Comment: Nice explanation with reference. +1

Comment: Thank you for much more detailed information. Question: `Transaction Log backup was performed with the option TRUNCATE_ONLY` - when this happens, is there any way to know this by T-SQL query?

Comment: `If you use my script from above and change the WHERE clause to match your database name, you might find out that that FULL backup that is not is_copy_only might just be a is_snapshot.` Yes - this was a `is_snapshot = 1`

Comment: Please can you clarify this point - `a FULL Database backup was taken without the COPY_ONLY` - how does it matter whether or not the copy only option was used? If both the full backups are lost, then the log backups are useless.

Comment: @variable I was trying to emphasize the point of having consistent chains of backups of `FULL` and `TLOG`. You've just uncovered a logical error in my example. Thank you. I will correct this.

Comment: @variable That example is only relevant when used in combination with the DIFF backup, which relies on the last FULL backup. It wold have to be expanded slightly to incorporate the DIFF part, but that would be out-of-scope for the current question.

Answer (score 1):

As per MSDN documentation [TRANSACTION LOG BACKUP and RESTORE SEQUENCE: Myths & Truths](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2010/08/26/transaction-log-backup-and-restore-sequence-myths-truths/) A continuous sequence of `T-Log` backups is tied by a `Log Chain`, which starts with a FULL backup. Now, unless we run anything explicitly that breaks the log-chain (Ex., running BACKUP log TRUNCATE_ONLY* or by switching to SIMPLE recovery model), the existing chain remains intact. With the log chain intact, you can restore your database from any FULL database backup in the media set, followed by all subsequent `T-Log` backups to the point of failure.

And as `MSSQLTIPS` documents [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3209/understanding-sql-server-log-sequence-numbers-for-backups/)  When restoring a database, the initial database [RESTORE](https://www.mssqltips.com/sql-server-tip-category/202/restore/) sequence must begin from a FULL database backup. A database RESTORE sequence cannot begin with a differential file backup or transaction log backup. When restoring databases there are four important LSNs: **`FirstLSN`**, **`LastLSN`**, **`CheckpointLSN`** and **`DatabaseBackupLSN`**.  These values can be retrieved from a SQL Server backup file using the [RESTORE HEADERONLY](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/105/how-to-get-the-contents-of-a-sql-server-backup-file/) command.

For Example

[image]

In the above screen shot I want to show you "Full Backup" Header and also "Transaction log Backup" header. If the Backup type is **1** , which means it is a header part of full backup . And if there is **2** that means , which is transaction log backup header.

[image]

In this screen shot I want to show you first  `Restore Headeronly`.. for Full Backup Then Transaction log Backup and again Full backup of the same database.

Note: Here I have highlighted some part in the screen shot due to security reason.

For your further ref [here](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/debunking-a-couple-of-myths-around-full-database-backups/) and [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/105/how-to-get-the-contents-of-a-sql-server-backup-file/)

Comment: Thanks for noting this `you can restore your database from any FULL database backup in the media set, followed by all subsequent T-Log backups to the point of failure`.

Comment: Also, the `AppAssure` was indeed doing the TRUNCATE LOG when it took a non COPY_ONLY backup !!

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question, I'm not convinced your "log chain" is broken because of this `Appsure` backup.  Assuming you can restore the `FULL` backup taken by `APPSURE` at line 5 `WITH NORECOVERY`, you should be able to restore your `DIFFERENTIAL` backup taken at line 6 without any problems.

I *believe* your real question is:

> How can I determine if '*rogue*' `FULL` non-copyonly backups are being
>   taken without my knowledge.

There might be more sophisticated ways of determining this, but *perhaps* a simple query to check for non-copyonly backups being stored on a location you were not expecting would suffice.

From your screenshot, it looks like your normal backups are being store at `E:\SQLBackups`.  It might be sufficient for you to run a simple query to check for `FULL` non-copyonly backups being stored somewhere else.

```
SELECT s.database_name
    ,m.physical_device_name
    ,s.backup_start_date
FROM msdb.dbo.backupset s
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily m ON s.media_set_id = m.media_set_id
WHERE s.database_name = DB_NAME() -- Remove this line for all the database
    AND s.is_copy_only = 0
    and physical_device_name not like 'E:\SQLBackup%'
ORDER BY backup_start_date DESC
```

Comment: The `AppAssure` backups up to some location and the meeting with IT team went like this - `they can provide us only the mdf and ldf files which is attachable`. So we cannot have it in NORECOVERY mode for further LOG restores. Thanks for the idea on the script to verify this and alert me whenever this happens.

Comment: Well - I guess you could still check for backups being created on locations that are not expected - that's the idea of the query I provided in my answer.