# DIFFs promoted to FULLs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup, ola-hallengren

We use Ola Hallengren's `DatabaseBackup` stored procedure to backup a load of SharePoint databases on a SQL Server 2012 instance into Azure blob storage. We have been doing this for quite a while without any issues. However, for the last 6 weeks our `DIFFs` are randomly being promoted to `FULL` and we cannot find out why.

This is the output from the agent step

> ```
> BACKUP DATABASE [Database] TO URL = N'https://strorgage.blob.core.windows.net/server/instance/Database/2020/11/diff/Database_FULL_20201105_200000.bak' 
> WITH NO_CHECKSUM, COMPRESSION, CREDENTIAL = N'*storeageaccountname*'
> ```

If you have a look at the generted URL you will note that the procedures is storing in the DIFF directory, but creating a FULL backup file.

```
https://strorgage.blob.core.windows.net/server/instance/Database/2020/11/diff/Database_FULL_20201105_200000.bak
                                                                        --^           --^
```

DatabaseBackup (Ola proc) is from 2019-06-14 so it needs an upgrade to be fair, but it has worked well for over 18 months.

We do not call Ola code directly as we have a small wrapper procedure which builds up the virtual path name for Azure, but essentially this is how we call Ola's code.

This is an issue were for some unknown reason DIFF backups are being promoted to FULL, this causes petabytes of Azure blob backups instead of gigabytes - each day.

```
EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseBackup
    @Database = @DatabaseName,
    @URL = @BackupPath,
    @Credential = @StorageAccount,
    @BackupType = @backupType,
    @Compress = @Compression,
    @LogToTable = 'Y',
    @ChangeBackupType = 'Y',
    @Updateability = @DatabaseReadOnlyState,
    @DirectoryStructure = NULL,
    @AvailabilityGroupDirectoryStructure = NULL
```

Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: If you take a FULL backup file that should be a DIFF and run `RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'Database_FULL_20201105_200000.bak'` what do you get in the `BackupType` column? 1 (FULL) or 5 (DIFF Database)?

Answer (score 6):

You say that this promotion of DIFF to FULL backups is "random" but I'd wager you can find a connection between this activity and data churn (or index maintenance) in the database itself.

Because you're using `ChangeBackupType='Y'`, the backup job is looking at [sys.dm_db_file_space_usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-file-space-usage-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to see how much of the database has been changed, and performs a FULL backup if it exceeds a threshold (I'm having difficulty discerning the default threshold from the source code). You can change that threshold by adjusting the `ModificationLevel` parameter, which is a percentage. From [the documentation](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html)

> **ModificationLevel**
> Specify a percentage when a differential backup will be changed to a full backup. This option can only be used together with @ChangeBackupType = 'Y'.
> DatabaseBackup checks allocated_extent_page_count and modified_extent_page_count in sys.dm_db_file_space_usage to calculate how much of a database that has been modified.

Answer (score 3):

## Introduction

Looking at your code, it seems that you are already using the `@ChangeBackupType` parameter Ola provided in his [SQL Server Maintenance Solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/) for the [DatabaseBackup](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) stored procedure. The documentation of this parameter provides the following bit of information:

> DatabaseBackup checks `differential_base_lsn` in `sys.master_files` to determine whether a differential backup can be performed. If a differential backup is not possible, then the database is skipped by default. **Alternatively, you can set ChangeBackupType to Y to have a full backup performed instead.**

<sup>relevant</sup>
...and...

> DatabaseBackup checks `last_log_backup_lsn` in `sys.database_recovery_status` to determine whether a transaction log backup in full or bulk-logged recovery model can be performed. If a transaction log backup is not possible, then the database is skipped by default. **Alternatively, you can set ChangeBackupType to Y to have a differential or full backup performed instead.**

<sup>not relevant</sup>

<sup>***Reference:** [DatabaseBackup](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) (ola.hallengren.com)*</sup>

## Assumption

Seeing as you are using the parameter in question and assuming that your databases are all running in FULL recovery model, then I would expect Ola' scripts to do as they were told and just perform a differential backup, like you were previously observing.....

## However

...something is altering the SharePoint databases in such a way, that Ola's procedure is assuming that the database requires a FULL backup. Ola checks various situations, one of which is based on the parameter....

### ModificationLevel

There is the additional parameter `@ModificationLevel` that would convert a DIFF backup to a FULL backup if the first parameter `@ChangeBackupType = 'Y'` is set. Looking at Ola's code provides us with this:

```
  IF @ModificationLevel IS NOT NULL AND @BackupType <> 'DIFF'
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Errors ([Message], Severity, [State])
    SELECT 'The value for the parameter @ModificationLevel is not supported.', 16, 3
  END
```

That means that if the parameter `@ModifcationLevel` is set to a value and `@ChangeBackupType` is set to `Y`, then the backup procedure will convert the DIFF backup to a FULL backup **If the amount of pages changed triggers the case**.

Because you haven't set `@ModificationLevel` it remains `NULL` as can be seen in Ola's code:

```
@ModificationLevel int = NULL,
```

This doesn't seem to be the case in your situation, unless of course your parameter's value for `@ModificationLevel` is not `NULL`.

## Solution 1

**In which case, we have found the culprit.** Change the value for `@ModificationLevel` back to `NULL` and all is well.

### Further Reasons for Conversion

Another reason the backup would change from `DIFF` to `FULL` is the parameter `@ChangeBackupType` itself.

The description (from above) was written as:

> DatabaseBackup (the procedure) checks `differential_base_lsn` in `sys.master_files` to determine whether a differential backup can be performed. If a differential backup is not possible, then the database is skipped by default. **Alternatively, you can set ChangeBackupType to Y to have a full backup performed instead.**

#### Chekcing the Code

Ola wrote this in the code:

> ```
> SELECT @CurrentDifferentialBaseLSN = differential_base_lsn
> FROM sys.master_files
> WHERE database_id = DB_ID(@CurrentDatabaseName)
> AND [type] = 0
> AND [file_id] = 1
> ```

and this part here:

> ```
>    IF @CurrentBackupType = 'DIFF'
>     BEGIN
>       SELECT @CurrentDifferentialBaseIsSnapshot = is_snapshot
>       FROM msdb.dbo.backupset
>       WHERE database_name = @CurrentDatabaseName
>       AND [type] = 'D'
>       AND checkpoint_lsn = @CurrentDifferentialBaseLSN
>     END
>
>     IF @ChangeBackupType = 'Y'
>     BEGIN
>       IF @CurrentBackupType = 'DIFF' AND @CurrentDifferentialBaseIsSnapshot = 1
>       BEGIN
>         SET @CurrentBackupType = 'FULL'
>       END
>     END;
> ```

What does this mean?

### Translating Ola's Code

Well it reads a bit like this:

1. Get the value of `differntial_base_lsn` for the current database
2. If the backup type is DIFF then...

   - Read the `is_snapshot` column in the `msdb.dbo.backupset` table for the current database with the `@CurrentDifferentialBaseLSN` and the backup `type` is `D` (Database backup)
   - If

     - `@ChanageBackupType is` Y` and
     - `@CurrentBackupType` is `DIFF and
     - `@CurrentDifferentialBaseIsSnapshot` is `1`
   - Then

     - Set `@CurrentBackupType` to `FULL`

Here you have a possible situation...

## Solution 2

...if your database was backed up by a third party solution (CommVault, NetApp, et. al.), then the 3-rd party solution will have created a valid and consistent database backup using the SQL Server VSS Writer service, which will make a note in the `msdb.dbo.backupset` that a snapshot copy of the database was taken, which sets the `is_snapshot` parameter for that database for the given `differntial_base_lsn` which your DIFF would be based upon.

Because of this the DIFF backup you are trying to perform can no longer be based on the `is_snapshot` backup and must create a new FULL backup again, to reset the `is_snapshot` and the `differntial_base_lsn` value, and to create a new base for future DIFF backups.

### Find the Other Backup

You will have to determine which 3rd-party (or other backup solutionb) is meddling with your implemented soltuion and ensure that they are either...

1. modified to co-exist
2. minimized to one backup solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Seems like we have additional backup via SQL Server VSS Writer. And this backup broke the backup chain. Will check diff backups couple of days.

Comment: @Oleksandr You're welcome. The script provided in my answer to [How to tell if a backup log chain is broken?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/204931/15356) will let you analyse the backup history to see who/what is performing additional backups.And my answer to the question [Will VSS backups break logchain?](https://serverfault.com/a/820843/145804) over on Server Fault will provide you with additional bits and peices regarding VSS Writer and snapshots.

Comment: I have been looking at this. When looking at the output in the GitHub issue, there is one thing missing. If the backup type was changed because of a VSS backup, then this should be logged as "Differential base is snapshot: Yes". However I don't see that in the output. I was checking the code and found a bug in the logging. The logging only happens when @CurrentBackupType = 'DIFF', but at that point in the code the backup type had already been changed. So nothing was logged. I have fixed this now. Could you please download the latest version.