# MS SQL Server: Log Backup LSN Mismatch

Tags: sql-server

We had to restore a database yesterday using a full backup and a number of log backups. This caused problems because the log chain was broken. All full and log backups were written. No backup job was failing, the corresponding log history looks like:

| Backup Type | Name | Start | End | First LSN | Last LSN | Checkpoint | Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Database Full | db_name | 12.01.2021 20:30:02 | 12.01.2021 20:30:04 | 171000001698500037 | 171000001700400001 | 171000001698500037 | 277955584 |
| Transaction Log | db_name | 12.01.2021 20:48:00 | 12.01.2021 20:48:00 | 171000001696100001 | 171000001701900001 | 171000001698500037 | 80896 |
| Transaction Log | db_name | 12.01.2021 21:12:00 | 12.01.2021 21:12:00 | 171000001701900001 | 171000001715000001 | 171000001702100002 | 146432 |
| Transaction Log | db_name | 12.01.2021 21:36:00 | 12.01.2021 21:36:00 | 171000001715000001 | 171000001740600001 | 171000001715200002 | 146432 |
| Transaction Log | db_name | 12.01.2021 22:00:01 | 12.01.2021 22:00:01 | 171000001740600001 | 171000001748500001 | 171000001740800002 | 80896 |
| Transaction Log | db_name | 12.01.2021 22:24:00 | 12.01.2021 22:24:00 | 171000001748500001 | 171000001751100001 | 171000001748700002 | 80896 |
| Transaction Log | db_name | 12.01.2021 22:48:00 | 12.01.2021 22:48:00 | 171000001751100001 | 171000001753400001 | 171000001751300002 | 80896 |
| Transaction Log | db_name | 12.01.2021 23:12:00 | 12.01.2021 23:12:00 | 171000001753400001 | 171000001755700001 | 171000001753600002 | 80896 |
| Transaction Log | db_name | 13.01.2021 00:00:00 | 13.01.2021 00:00:00 | 171000001756300001 | 171000001756700001 | 171000001756500002 | 80896 |
| Transaction Log | db_name | 13.01.2021 00:24:00 | 13.01.2021 00:24:00 | 171000001756700001 | 171000001757100001 | 171000001756900002 | 80896 |
| Transaction Log | db_name | 13.01.2021 00:48:00 | 13.01.2021 00:48:00 | 171000001757100001 | 171000001757500001 | 171000001757300002 | 80896 |
| Transaction Log | db_name | 13.01.2021 01:12:00 | 13.01.2021 01:12:00 | 171000001757500001 | 171000001757900001 | 171000001757700002 | 80896 |
| Transaction Log | db_name | 13.01.2021 01:36:01 | 13.01.2021 01:36:01 | 171000001757900001 | 171000001758300001 | 171000001758100002 | 80896 |
| Transaction Log | db_name | 13.01.2021 02:00:00 | 13.01.2021 02:00:00 | 171000001758300001 | 171000001758700001 | 171000001758500002 | 80896 |
| Transaction Log | db_name | 13.01.2021 02:24:00 | 13.01.2021 02:24:00 | 171000001758700001 | 171000001799800001 | 171000001758900002 | 277504 |
| Transaction Log | db_name | 13.01.2021 02:48:01 | 13.01.2021 02:48:01 | 171000001799800001 | 171000001810300001 | 171000001807500037 | 80896 |
| Transaction Log | db_name | 13.01.2021 03:12:00 | 13.01.2021 03:12:01 | 171000001810300001 | 171000001947400001 | 171000001810500002 | 736256 |
| Transaction Log | db_name | 13.01.2021 03:36:00 | 13.01.2021 03:36:00 | 171000001947400001 | 171000001958500001 | 171000001947600002 | 80896 |
| Transaction Log | db_name | 13.01.2021 04:00:00 | 13.01.2021 04:00:00 | 171000001958500001 | 171000001960300001 | 171000001959000002 | 80896 |
| Transaction Log | db_name | 13.01.2021 04:24:00 | 13.01.2021 04:24:00 | 171000001960300001 | **171000001961400001** | 171000001960500002 | 80896 |
| Transaction Log | db_name | 13.01.2021 04:48:01 | 13.01.2021 04:48:01 | **171000001962000001** | 171000001963800001 | 171000001962200002 | 80896 |
| Transaction Log | db_name | 13.01.2021 05:12:00 | 13.01.2021 05:12:00 | 171000001963800001 | 171000001964200001 | 171000001964000002 | 80896 |
| Transaction Log | db_name | 13.01.2021 05:36:00 | 13.01.2021 05:36:00 | 171000001964200001 | 171000001964600001 | 171000001964400002 | 80896 |

As you can see, the chain is broken at 13.01.2021 04:48:01. What could be the reason? A VM reset? A problem with Veeam (Backup Software)? An inconsistency with the backup plan? I rather see the problem outside of SQL Server because we've checked the full and log backup today morning and the chain is again complete and a test restore was working fine. Test restores in the past always worked.

As said before. The backup jobs terminated all successfully.

I appreciate your input. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps a BACKUP LOG ... TO NULL has been done ? At what time did the VEAM backup is executed ? (I never tolerate VEAM backup for my own customers because its interfere with my own backup plans....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something weird is going on here. I first suspected that the database was put into simple recovery mode and back to full. But SQL server won't allow you to take a log backup after such operation. I.e., the log backup with firstLSN 171000001962000001 should have failed unless there was a full backup before.

The only two things I can think of is that you are leaving out the full backup that above log backup should be based on (i.e., my above scenario) in the presentation of backup history. Or that the backup history was manipulated to either delete the row for that full backup, or a log backup was indeed taken and *that* row from backuphistory was deleted.

Unless you are on a super-old SQL server, of course (2005). Those had weird options for the BACKUP LOG command.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much! You got me to the right track! The information in my table above was taken from the backup files.

Following SQL statement

```
SELECT 
    name, description, user_name, backup_start_date, backup_finish_date, type, first_lsn, last_lsn, checkpoint_lsn, database_backup_lsn
FROM
    msdb.dbo.backupset 
WHERE
     msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name IN (SELECT [name] FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases)
    AND msdb.dbo.backupset.database_name LIKE 'db_name'
    AND msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_start_date BETWEEN '2021-01-13 20:00:00.000' AND '2021-01-14 20:00:00.000'
ORDER BY backup_start_date
```

shows that the backup solution takes a unnecessary full backup (what is not the problem).

The problem is a log backup taken by a other user. Thats the file I don't have. Wired... but we are able to solve it with the information.

| name | description | user_name | backup_start_date | backup_finish_date | type | first_lsn | last_lsn | checkpoint_lsn | database_backup_lsn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | sql-server | 2021-01-12 20:30:02.000 | 2021-01-12 20:30:04.000 | D | 171000001698500037 | 171000001700400001 | 171000001698500037 | 170000001098100037 |
| NULL | NULL | sql-server | 2021-01-12 20:48:00.000 | 2021-01-12 20:48:00.000 | L | 171000001696100001 | 171000001701900001 | 171000001698500037 | 171000001698500037 |
| NULL | NULL | sql-server | 2021-01-12 21:12:00.000 | 2021-01-12 21:12:00.000 | L | 171000001701900001 | 171000001715000001 | 171000001702100002 | 171000001698500037 |
| NULL | NULL | sql-server | 2021-01-12 21:36:00.000 | 2021-01-12 21:36:00.000 | L | 171000001715000001 | 171000001740600001 | 171000001715200002 | 171000001698500037 |
| NULL | NULL | sql-server | 2021-01-12 22:00:01.000 | 2021-01-12 22:00:01.000 | L | 171000001740600001 | 171000001748500001 | 171000001740800002 | 171000001698500037 |
| NULL | NULL | sql-server | 2021-01-12 22:24:00.000 | 2021-01-12 22:24:00.000 | L | 171000001748500001 | 171000001751100001 | 171000001748700002 | 171000001698500037 |
| NULL | NULL | sql-server | 2021-01-12 22:48:00.000 | 2021-01-12 22:48:00.000 | L | 171000001751100001 | 171000001753400001 | 171000001751300002 | 171000001698500037 |
| NULL | NULL | sql-server | 2021-01-12 23:12:00.000 | 2021-01-12 23:12:00.000 | L | 171000001753400001 | 171000001755700001 | 171000001753600002 | 171000001698500037 |
| NULL | NULL | sql-server | 2021-01-12 23:36:00.000 | 2021-01-12 23:36:00.000 | L | 171000001755700001 | 171000001756300001 | 171000001756100002 | 171000001698500037 |
| NULL | NULL | sql-server | 2021-01-13 00:00:00.000 | 2021-01-13 00:00:00.000 | L | 171000001756300001 | 171000001756700001 | 171000001756500002 | 171000001698500037 |
| NULL | NULL | sql-server | 2021-01-13 00:24:00.000 | 2021-01-13 00:24:00.000 | L | 171000001756700001 | 171000001757100001 | 171000001756900002 | 171000001698500037 |
| NULL | NULL | sql-server | 2021-01-13 00:48:00.000 | 2021-01-13 00:48:00.000 | L | 171000001757100001 | 171000001757500001 | 171000001757300002 | 171000001698500037 |
| NULL | NULL | sql-server | 2021-01-13 01:12:00.000 | 2021-01-13 01:12:00.000 | L | 171000001757500001 | 171000001757900001 | 171000001757700002 | 171000001698500037 |
| NULL | NULL | sql-server | 2021-01-13 01:36:01.000 | 2021-01-13 01:36:01.000 | L | 171000001757900001 | 171000001758300001 | 171000001758100002 | 171000001698500037 |
| NULL | NULL | sql-server | 2021-01-13 02:00:00.000 | 2021-01-13 02:00:00.000 | L | 171000001758300001 | 171000001758700001 | 171000001758500002 | 171000001698500037 |
| NULL | NULL | sql-server | 2021-01-13 02:24:00.000 | 2021-01-13 02:24:00.000 | L | 171000001758700001 | 171000001799800001 | 171000001758900002 | 171000001698500037 |
| Veeam Backup & Replication | Image-level backup | NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM | 2021-01-13 02:33:24.000 | 2021-01-13 02:33:37.000 | D | 171000001807500037 | 171000001809300001 | 171000001807500037 | 171000001698500037 |
| NULL | NULL | sql-server | 2021-01-13 02:48:01.000 | 2021-01-13 02:48:01.000 | L | 171000001799800001 | 171000001810300001 | 171000001807500037 | 171000001807500037 |
| NULL | NULL | sql-server | 2021-01-13 03:12:00.000 | 2021-01-13 03:12:01.000 | L | 171000001810300001 | 171000001947400001 | 171000001810500002 | 171000001807500037 |
| NULL | NULL | sql-server | 2021-01-13 03:36:00.000 | 2021-01-13 03:36:00.000 | L | 171000001947400001 | 171000001958500001 | 171000001947600002 | 171000001807500037 |
| NULL | NULL | sql-server | 2021-01-13 04:00:00.000 | 2021-01-13 04:00:00.000 | L | 171000001958500001 | 171000001960300001 | 171000001959000002 | 171000001807500037 |
| NULL | NULL | sql-server | 2021-01-13 04:24:00.000 | 2021-01-13 04:24:00.000 | L | 171000001960300001 | 171000001961400001 | 171000001960500002 | 171000001807500037 |
| NULL | NULL | admin | 2021-01-13 04:35:46.000 | 2021-01-13 04:35:46.000 | L | 171000001961400001 | 171000001962000001 | 171000001961600002 | 171000001807500037 |
| NULL | NULL | sql-server | 2021-01-13 04:48:01.000 | 2021-01-13 04:48:01.000 | L | 171000001962000001 | 171000001963800001 | 171000001962200002 | 171000001807500037 |
| NULL | NULL | sql-server | 2021-01-13 05:12:00.000 | 2021-01-13 05:12:00.000 | L | 171000001963800001 | 171000001964200001 | 171000001964000002 | 171000001807500037 |

Thank you very much. You helped me to nail down the issue.

Best
Frederik

Comment: The fact that Veeam does a full backup isn't the problem (as you noted). This is the VSS snapshot that Veem produces of your machine, it is seen by SQL Server as a full backup, thanks to the integration with the SQL Server VSS Writer service. The problem is that other log backup, which you need to hunt down if you want to restore and also hunt down why this happened and make sure it doesn't happen again. :-)

Comment: If you take my script from [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/204931/15356) and look at the `msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily.physical_device_name` column, then you know where the file was stored that the **admin** user created. Put in the correct database name in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks. We did that and found out there was a "shrink database log file" job activated in Veeam which did break the log setup on our side ;-)